# A ring that is left Noetherian but not right noetherian

Tags: ring-theory, modules, noetherian

I am studying Chapter 8 of Hungerford for my qualifying exam.

In Chapter 8.1., he gives an exercise concerning the ring that is right Noetherian (resp. Artinian) but not left Noetherian (resp. Artinian).

> The ring of all $2\times 2$ matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}$ such that $a$ is an integer and $b,c$ are rational is right Noetherian but not left Noetherian.

Basically, this question has been answered several times: for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433855/left-noetherian-ring-but-not-right-noetherian-ring?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596343/a-difficulty-in-solving-a-question-in-chapter-8-hungerford?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Showing that the above ring, say $R$, is not left Noetherian is quite straightforward; we simply construct an infinitely ascending chain of left ideals in $R$.

Almost every sources (including [this site](https://planetmath.org/exampleofarightnoetherianringthatisnotleftnoetherian)) argue that $R$ is right Noetherian by showing that a right ideal $I$ is finitely generated. In particular, they separate cases where (i) $I$ contains an element of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}$ with $a\neq 0$, and (ii) $I$ consists of elements of the form $\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}$. But I don’t see why the following (simpler) argument can be applied:

> A ring $R$ is a right Noetherian if and only if for some ideal $I$ of $R$, both $I$ and $R/I$ are Noetherian. Define a map $\phi:R\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Q}$ by $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ 0&c\end{pmatrix}\mapsto (a,c)$. Then $\phi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with kernel $I=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}:b\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$. $R/I\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is Noetherian since both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are. The only submodule contained in $I$ is $0$ and $I$ itself, since if $J\subset I$ is a nontrivial submodule of $I$, then for some nonzero $\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\in J$ we have $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1/b\end{pmatrix}\in J$. It follows that both $R/I$ and $I$ are Noetherian.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did precisely that in [one of the solutions you linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2598297/29335), although I chose different submodules to prove it with, ones which link with the classification of right ideals of the ring.

The thing that deserves more explanation in what you said is "$\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Q$ is Noetherian."  Remember, you have to show that it's Noetherian as a right $R$ **module**.  It's tempting to just say "the two things are Noetherian **rings** so the product is a Noetherian ring" and that is true, but a third party could legitimately question why this Noetherian ring should be a Noetherian right module over $R$.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks for the explanation!